# Return correct enum without using if

Tags: java, enums

I have task to change this if:

```
if (userDecision.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
    return DirectoriesActivity.DELETE;
} else if (userDecision.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
    return DirectoriesActivity.REPLACE;
} else {
    return DirectoriesActivity.ADD_NEW_CONTENTS;
}
```

On something what will return just enum without using if. I have to use some enum properties but I don't know which one :/ Here is my enum:

```
public enum DirectoriesActivity {
    DELETE,
    REPLACE,
    ADD_NEW_CONTENTS;
}
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
public enum DirectoriesActivity {
    DELETE ("D"),
    REPLACE ("R"),
    ADD_NEW_CONTENTS ("A");

    private String directoriesActivityCode;
    private DirectoriesActivity(String directoriesActivityCode)    {
        this.directoriesActivityCode = directoriesActivityCode;
    }

    public DirectoriesActivity getEnum(String x){
        //no idea what to do here
    }
}
```

Or maybe somebody have some other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
public enum DirectoriesActivity {
    DELETE ("D"),
    REPLACE ("R"),
    ADD_NEW_CONTENTS ("A");

    private String directoriesActivityCode;

    private DirectoriesActivity(String directoriesActivityCode)    {
        this.directoriesActivityCode = directoriesActivityCode;
    }    

    public DirectoriesActivity getEnum(String x){
        for (DirectoriesActivity directoriesActivity : values()) {
            if (directoriesActivity.directoriesActivityCode.equals(x)) {
                return directoriesActivity;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value " + x);
    }
}
```

Or in case you are using Java 8

```
return Arrays.stream(DirectoriesActivity.values())
            .filter(directoriesActivity -> directoriesActivity.directoriesActivityCode.equals(userDecision))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value " + userDecision));
```

*Important side note* here is that this solution is performing a lot worse than the solution provided by Peter.  But as long as performance is not an issue, I'd prefer a solution like this.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I suppose the question is to rewrite the 'client code' without an `if`?  That could be refactored to `DirectoriesActivity.getEnum(userDecision)` then.

Comment: One if can be :P Just I can't use for example 20x IF (to don't have situation if(a) elseif(b) elseif(c) ... elseif(z)).

Comment: @MarekS my example doesn't use any `if` and is much, much faster. For 20 constants it will be at least 20x faster.

Comment: this is from far the worst sollution proposed... @PeterLawrey is the most efficient... you may don't understand it at the begining, but please, take a look, test it and realize using a `for-loop` each time to retrieve an Enum is not a good option.

Comment: In terms of performance it's not the best solution, but there are lots of other aspects in deciding which option to choose.  Performance is only one of them.

Comment: @wjans tell-me just one aspect (except plain code understanding if you dont know OOP paradigm) which makes your approach best than peter's one please, because I really can't see it...

Comment: @JordiCastilla Easier to read code seems (indeed) more important to me in this scenario.  Especially since enum values already suggest that IO will follow and OP was already heading in this direction, and needs to decide which approach to take.  It is an important note that there is a performance drawback, but that has been mentioned...

Comment: so... after writting a lot without saying nothing, you didn't found a single one, right? what a pitty bro.... here we're to learn so if OP was going into a bad direction please gide him to right one!!! Your option, although valid, is not the best, just this... don't be mad don't explain your life...

Comment: To me thats _more_ important. Indeed here to learn, multiple alternatives should be mentioned.  I'll update the answer to emphasise this.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a Map lookup.

```
static Map<String, DirectoriesActivity> lookup = new HashMap<>();

static {
    // iterate over all the values and 
    // put the value we want to lookup as the key to the map.
    for(DirectoriesActivity da: values())
        lookup.put(da.directoriesActivitCode, da);
}

public static DirectoriesActivity lookup(String s) {
    // lookup the map we built in the static block.
    return s == null ? null : lookup.get(s.toUppercase());
}
```

This way you can add as many codes as you want without having to change the code.

Comment: Much better than switch

Comment: @SashaSalauyou thats why Peter is master with 281k rep , and me just a poor aprentice xDDDD

Comment: @JordiCastilla  we're here to learn, I believe even Peter learned much during his years on StackOverflow )

Comment: Aren't static blocks supposed to execute while class instantiates? Why is values() able to give all the enums during this time?

Comment: @Codebender this code works precisely (used many times in practice). `static` is executed after values creation.

Comment: @Codebender I'm more surprised why OP accepted more verbose and inefficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change enum names to D, R, A then you can use built-in feature:

```
public enum DirectoriesActivity {D,R,A}
DirectoriesActivity activity = DirectoriesActivity.valueOf("D");
```

`valueOf` throws IllegalArgumentException if string is not match.