# java universal set function

Tags: java, class, set, universal

I was thinking how implement set function to all fields, like in Calendar class.

```
public class Test
{
    int a,b;

// constructor, etc

    set(int field, int value)
    {
    //--
    }
}


//========
Test t = new Test();
t.set(Test.a, 5);
```

How set body should look?

Comment: What do you mean by Universal function ?

Comment: This rather far away from what real Java looks like.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), try to make it work and then come back here if you have problems with actual code.

Comment: Make your `Test` class a `Map` and you are done. The `set` method would be called `put` then.

Comment: If you can access `Test.a` from outside, why do you need a setter at all?

Comment: Yuck. (But still plus one for the well-posed question even if the idea is bonkers.) What's so wrong with setA, setB etc? At least then they can be different types. The designers of the calendar class had a good reason for their approach; you probably don't.

Comment: I'm just curious how that code can look, nothing else

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz An even closer match is the `EnumMap`, giving you a degree of static safety.

Comment: @Jump3r Have you reviewed `Calendar` code to see how it looks?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Where I can fing Calendar code? I can't open that in jre/rt.jar

Comment: Are you using a JRE instead of a JDK? Source code is already included in a JDK installation and all IDEs give it to you automatically when you open that class. You also have the option of visiting the grepcode site.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Oh, I didn't see src.zip file and searched in jre folder. Thank you, gonna have look of that

Comment: @Jump3r look at my answer to find `Calendar` (or any other) source code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define an `enum` with the possible values for `field` and then act consequently:

```
public enum Field {
    MONTH, DAY, YEAR;
}


public void set(Field field, int value) {
    switch(field) {
    case MONTH:
        // use value to add months
    break;
    case YEAR:
        // use value to add years
    break;
    case DAY:
        // use value to add days
    break;
    }
}
```

you can also define a `Map` for your enum and define a lookup as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32134992/3850595)

**UPDATE**

> Where I can fing Calendar code?

In [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=calendar%20java) you will find any version  you need

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try using [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). Using it your code should look something like this:

`public void set(String fieldName, Object value){
     Field f1 = this.getClass().getField(fieldName);
     f1.set(this.getClass(),value); 
  }`

Be aware that this approach has many caveats and it does not follow Java development philosophy. Use Reflection API only if you are sure on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

No there's no way to pass some sort of field identifier into a method.

There are a number of ways to achieve a similar effect. The simplest is probably an `EnumMap`. Something like:

```
enum Field {
    AGE,
    HEIGHT;
}

EnumMap<Field,Integer> values;

values.put(Field.AGE, 18);
```

If you particularly want to have different fields for each value then you can embed the logic for setting and getting in the enum.

```
class Person {

    private int age;
    private int height;
    private int weight;

    public enum Field {

        AGE((p, n) -> p.age = n, p -> p.age),
        HEIGHT((p, n) -> p.height = n, p -> p.height),
        WEIGHT((p, n) -> p.weight = n, p -> p.weight);

        private final BiConsumer<Person, Integer> setter;
        private final Function<Person, Integer> getter;

        Field(BiConsumer<Person, Integer> setter, Function<Person, Integer> getter) {
            this.setter = setter;
            this.getter = getter;
        }
    }

    public void set(Field field, int val) {
        field.setter.accept(this, val);
    }

    public int get(Field field) {
        return field.getter.apply(this);
    }
}

Person person = new Person();
person.set(Person.Field.AGE, 22);
int age = person.get(Person.Field.AGE);
```

If you aren't using Java 8 you can avoid all the lambdas but the code is a lot longer.

This is better than using a `switch` statement. `switch` statements are evil. Anyone who uses them should be switched ;-) Ok I admit I sometimes use them but I always wash my hands well afterwards.

Comment: This seems more convenient than burdening the class with a `switch` statement to map the enum member to a actual instance variable. The switch would have to be repeated in each public method.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I added an option that uses fields instead of a map - I presume that's why OP accepted the other answer. But I hate switch statements for the reason you gave so wanted to provide an alternative.